# Get psycopg2 count(*) number of results

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

What is the correct way to get the number or rows returned by this query? I'm specifically looking to see if no results are returned.

```
sql = 'SELECT count(*) from table WHERE guid = %s;'
data=[guid]
cur.execute(sql,data)
results = cur.fetchone()
for r in results:
  print type(r) # Returns as string {'count': 0L} Or {'count': 1L}
```

Comment: count will return only 1 row (in this case)

Comment: `type(r)` will **not** return as `{'count': 0L}`. Most likely it'll print `<type 'dict'>` or similar.

Comment: type(r) returning {'count': 0L} was directly from the console.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`results` is itself a row object, in your case (judging by the claimed `print` output), a dictionary (you probably configured a [dict-like cursor subclass](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor)); simply access the `count` key:

```
result = cur.fetchone()
print result['count']
```

Because you used `.fetchone()` only one row is returned, not a list of rows.

If you are *not* using a dict(-like) row cursor, rows are tuples and the count value is the first value:

```
result = cur.fetchone()
print result[0]
```

Comment: You write: "rows are tuples and the count value is the first value".  What is the second value? When I do a count(*), I get "(1,)" back (for a table with count=1). What is the second value in the Tuple?

Comment: @BertC: there is just one value, unless you change the `SELECT` list to produce more values. Like `SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(some_column) FROM table` would produce a single row with two values.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to those coming across this thread, here is a way to count all the rows for each table in your database using Python:

```
total_count = 0

with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("""SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
           WHERE table_schema = 'public'""")

    for table in cur.fetchall():
        table_name = table[0]
        cur.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table}").format(table=sql.Identifier(table_name)))
        table_count = cur.fetchone()
        result = f'TABLE NAME: {table_name}, COUNT: {table_count}'
        total_count += int(table_count[0])
        print(result)

print(total_count)
```

Answer (score -4):

The following worked for me

```
cur.execute('select * from table where guid = %s;',[guid])
rows = cur.fetchall()
print 'ResultCount = %d' % len(rows)
```

**Drawback:**
This will not be very efficient for the DBMS if **all** you need is the count.

Comment: I know this is old but surely it will always return 1 row? so len(rows) will always be 1?

Comment: I am using the `fetchall` function. If I were using the `fetchone` function, I believe you would be right. EDIT: I see what you mean: the SQL query will always return one row, which means `len(rows)` will always be 1. I think I should remove the aggregate `count` function from the query to show what I meant. Thank you

Comment: @alejando either that, or leave the aggregate in the query, use fetchone, and then extract the aggregate from row tuple returned. i.e. 

cur.execute('select count(*) from table'); 
row = cur.fetchone(); 
count = row[0]; 

this will be much more efficient if the rowset is large

Comment: Agreed. That's why I mentioned the drawback in my answer. However, if I change it to what you suggest I might as well erase my answer as it would stop contributing anything to anyone that comes to this question. I think some people could benefit from using the `fetchall` function.